# Gulp stops rebundling after few times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm doing Wes Bos' react tutorials, but after few gulp rebundling it stops working and stops on this app state. It's really frustrating, because everytime something doesn't work I have to check if it's code or gulp just stopped working.

Here is my gulp code:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');

var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback')


/*
  Styles Task
*/

gulp.task('styles',function() {
  // move over fonts

  gulp.src('css/fonts/**.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/fonts'))

  // Compiles CSS
  gulp.src('css/style.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
});

/*
  Images
*/
gulp.task('images',function(){
  gulp.src('css/images/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/images'))
});

/*
  Browser Sync
*/
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        // we need to disable clicks and forms for when we test multiple rooms
        server : {},
        middleware : [ historyApiFallback() ],
        ghostMode: false
    });
});

function handleErrors() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  notify.onError({
    title: 'Compile Error',
    message: '<%= error.message %>'
  }).apply(this, args);
  this.emit('end'); // Keep gulp from hanging on this task
}

function buildScript(file, watch) {
  var props = {
    entries: ['./scripts/' + file],
    debug : true,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    transform:  [babelify.configure({stage : 0 })]
  };

  // watchify() if watch requested, otherwise run browserify() once
  var bundler = watch ? watchify(browserify(props)) : browserify(props);

  function rebundle() {
    var stream = bundler.bundle();
    return stream
      .on('error', handleErrors)
      .pipe(source(file))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
      // If you also want to uglify it
      // .pipe(buffer())
      // .pipe(uglify())
      // .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
      // .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
      .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
  }

  // listen for an update and run rebundle
  bundler.on('update', function() {
    rebundle();
    gutil.log('Rebundle...');
  });

  // run it once the first time buildScript is called
  return rebundle();
}

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return buildScript('main.js', false); // this will run once because we set watch to false
});

// run 'scripts' task first, then watch for future changes
gulp.task('default', ['images','styles','scripts','browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('css/**/*', ['styles']); // gulp watch for stylus changes
  return buildScript('main.js', true); // browserify watch for JS changes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the error catching does not tell the app to continue. In order to catch errors and prevent them from stopping the process, use a plugin like `gulp-plumber`.

Use `gulp-plumber` by adding the following one pipe in the build process

First, require the `gulp-plumber` plugin:

```
 var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
```

Then, add this code to your gulp task: (ideally right after your `.src()` function)

```
.pipe(plumber({
  errorHandler: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
  }
}))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's that, because it still looks like it's watching for changes, but if I save it doesn't rebundle.

Answer (score 0):

Create a callback

```
gulp.task('styles',function(cb) {
  // move over fonts

  gulp.src('css/fonts/**.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/fonts'))

  // Compiles CSS
  gulp.src('css/style.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'), cb());
});
```

This lets the stream know when a task has finished